# How can I translate an image into Magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, avs-fastsimpleimport

Is there a way to store images per StoreView separately?
If not, how could a solution look like?

It is a webshop with more than 15 languages, some pictures have certificates, which are valid only for the respective country.

I would like to avoid to explicitly set pictures to "disabled".

Comment: Are we talking about pictures on CMS pages, products, categories...?

Comment: Base Image, Small Image and Thumbnail are not configurable per store view, so there is no way to just: 1) use store switcher to change current store view 2) set new image(s) 3) save product 4) flush cache 5) check your changes on product view page. Instead of trying to hack magento, from product owner / customer perspective, product with certified image is different than one without a cert. Maybe consider to introduce new type of products for all certified ? Just thinking out loud.

Comment: Sorry, I should have written more detailed.
These are the products. Category images can be saved separately. In the CMS, you can use other images per view.

Comment: About products with their own attribute set, I have already thought. But I am surprised that there is no existing solution. The problem is certainly more often before?

Answer (score 0):

Yes can achieve that kind of thing in magento.

1) First add different theme in store wise.

2) add exception theme put your main theme in exception.

3) add image with same name in your store theme.

If magento wont find image and all then it will check in exception theme. other wise it will take from your store theme.

this way you can achieve theme things that you want